# Flag event is invoked twice on double submission of flag confirmation form

Tags: flags, event-subscribers

The method invoked during the flagging event is implemented in Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface.

```
class JIEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface{

  protected $staticCache;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->staticCache = &drupal_static("migration_running");
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[Drupal\flag\Event\FlagEvents::ENTITY_FLAGGED] = ['onFlag',10];
    return $events;
  }

  public function onFlag(Drupal\flag\Event\FlaggingEvent $event){
   $flagging = $event->getFlagging();
   $entity = $flagging->getFlaggable();
   $flag_id = $flagging->getFlagId();
   if($flag_id == 'relevant_id'){
      Node::create(..);
   }

  }
}
```

The service is registered in services.yml as:

```
services:
  my_custom.event_subscriber:
      class: Drupal\my_custom\EventSubscriber\JIEventSubscriber
      arguments: ['@entity_type.manager']
      tags:
        - { name: 'event_subscriber' }
```

The flagging of flag 'relevant_id' is done through confirmation form. When the confirmation button is clicked twice simultaneously, two nodes are created. I've removed JS click `eventListeners` on the confirmation button after the first click but is there no way to prevent this on server side?